# How to print out value from coredata dictionary in swift 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'username?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to print out the value "username" from my coredata entity.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

if (results?.count > 0) {

    for result: AnyObject in results! {
        println(result.username)
    }
}
```

The line             println(result.username) is giving me a compile error of 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'username'.

Comment: Does for result: NSDictionary in results work? Otherwise, try to use var resultDict:NSDictionary = result as NSDictionary to down cast it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast the array of managed object to the correct type:

```
for result in results! as [Users] {
    println(result.username)
}
```

This assumes that you have created a managed object subclass for the "Users" entity.

You should also distinguish whether `executeFetchRequest()` returned `nil`
(i.e. the fetch request failed), or `0` (i.e. no objects found),
and use the `error` parameter:

```
var error : NSError?
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) {
    if (results.count > 0) {
        for result in results as [Users] {
            println(result.username)
        }
    } else {
        println("No Users")
    }
} else {
    println("Fetch failed: \(error)")
    // Handle error ...
}
```

Update for **Swift 2/Xcode 7** with try/catch error handling:

```
do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Users]
    if (results.count > 0) {
        for result in results {
            print(result.username)
        }
    } else {
        print("No Users")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Note that the forced cast `as! [Users]` is acceptable here.
The returned objects are always instances of the corresponding class as configured in the Core Data model inspector, otherwise you have
a *programming error* which should be detected early.

Answer (score 1):

[Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458209/how-to-print-out-value-from-coredata-dictionary-in-swift-anyobject-does-not-ha/26459060#26459060) definitely lets you access the properties of your object, but the cast is forced. Like it or not, Swift's strong type system is the future. When returning results from a fetch request, you might consider testing for the type.

```
func executeFetchRequestT<T:AnyObject>(request:NSFetchRequest, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext, error: NSErrorPointer = nil) -> [T]? {
    var localError: NSError? = nil

    if let results:[AnyObject] = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &localError) {
        if results.count > 0 {
            if results[0] is T {
                let casted:[T] = results as [T]
                return .Some(casted)
            }

            if error != nil {
                error.memory = NSError(domain: "error_domain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Object in fetched results is not the expected type."])
            }

        } else if 0 == results.count {
            return [T]() // just return an empty array
        }
    }

    if error != nil && localError != nil {
        error.memory = localError!
    }

    return .None
}
```

Using this approach you can type your results and get an error if the type is incorrect.

```
var fetchError:NSError? = nil

if let results:[Users] = executeFetchRequestT(fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, error: &fetchError) {

    for user in results {
        // access the results with confidence of the correct type
    }

} else {

    // should have an error condition, handle it appropriately
    assertFailure("something bad happened")

}
```

Comment: When executing a fetch request for a entity (such as "Users" in this example), the returned objects are always instances of the corresponding class as configured in the Core Data model inspector.

Comment: Not always. The difference is subtle, but important. Casting without a test could lead to a crash. Today, I would use an `if let ... as? [EntityType]` as a safeguard.

Comment: Assuming that the entity is correctly configured in the Core Data model inspector: Under what circumstances would the fetch request not return `User` objects?

Comment: Depends entirely on how the NSFetchRequest is configured.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this

```
     for result: AnyObject in results! {

            if let user: AnyObject = result.valueForKey("username") {

                println(user)

            }

        }
```

The fix is using valueForKey("String")