# Swift: Fetch CoreData as Array

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift

I want to fetch all Saved Data in the sqlite table.

I'm currently doing this:

```
 func GetAllData() -> NSArray
{
    var error : NSError? = nil;
    var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations");
    let result : [AnyObject] = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error:&error)!;
      var elements : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
    for fetchedObject in result
    {
        elements.addObject(fetchedObject[0]);
    }
    print(elements);
    return elements;
}
```

I have no problems to fetch Data in Objective-C but in swift I dont get it!

The saving of the data works fine. I have two rows "Name" and "Category". How can I show all saved data?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should load all your Objects from CoreData into an Array/Dict of NSManaged Objects.

For Example:

```swift
    var locations  = [Locations]() // Where Locations = your NSManaged Class

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
    locations = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Locations]

    // Then you can use your properties.

    for location in locations {

      print(location.name)   

    }
```

Comment: `executeFetchRequest()` returns an *optional* which is `nil` if the fetch request fails. If you forcefully cast to `[Locations]` then the app will crash in that case. (Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/26459060/1187415.)

Comment: You might consider a [typed approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27365921/482529).

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
        
do {
     let results   = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
     let locations = results as! [Locations]
        
     for location in locations {
       print(location)   
     }

} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not fetch \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3**

```
func fetchData(){

    onlyDateArr.removeAll()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "PhotoData")

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let  dateCreated = results as! [PhotoData]

        for _datecreated in dateCreated {
            print(_datecreated.dateCreation!)
            onlyDateArr.append(_datecreated)
        }
    }catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }


}
```

Comment: All retrived nsmanagedObject stays in memory even if the viewcontroller deinit properly.

Answer (score 6):

## 2020 syntax

to copy and paste

```
func grabAllPersons() {
    var pp: [CD_Person] = []
    do {
        let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CD_Person")
        let f = try core.container.viewContext.fetch(r)
        pp = f as! [CD_Person]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("woe grabAllPersons \(error)")
    }
    
    for p: CD_Person in pp {
        print(" >> \(p.firstName)")
    }
}
```

Note that `core.container.viewContext` is "your" context, often (but not always) the one supplied by `core.container.viewContext`.  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040409/294884))

## Critical tip...

In some cases:

it is **ABSOLUTELY** important that you do not accidentally use the **"wrong"** context.

For example, you are doing a minor incidental issue, such as counting or just grabbing all the items.

This issue is explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60249306/294884) under the large heading "exercise extreme caution..."

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to (force) cast any result from NSFetchRequest:

```
var locations  = [Locations]()
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Locations>(entityName: "Locations") //Note the <Locations> makes the NSFetchRequestResult to an array of Locations 
locations = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
 
for location in locations {
    print(location.name)   
}
```

---

Another note: Usually you should name your entities in singular like "Location", not "Locations". And then an array of Location are locations. `let locations = Array<Location>(location1, location2)`

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
    {
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        return (delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
    }


    class func saveObeject (name:String,roll:String,college:String)
    {
        let context =  getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CountryInfo", in: context)

        let manageObjet = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        manageObjet.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        manageObjet.setValue(roll, forKey: "roll")
        manageObjet.setValue(college, forKey: "college")


        do
        {
            try context.save()
        }catch
        {
            print("unable to save data")
        }
    }

    class func getCountryDetail(name:String) ->Array<Any>?
    {

        // return "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-J9emWhBZ_OM/TtQgVQmBHRI/AAAAAAAAD2w/j7JJMRMiuAU/s1600/Al_Ain_FC.png"
        let contecxt = getContext()
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<CountryInfo> = CountryInfo.fetchRequest()

        var user:[CountryInfo] = []
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name LIKE[cd] %@",name)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do{
            user =  try contecxt.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let ClubInfoBO = user
            print(ClubInfoBO)
            return (ClubInfoBO) as? Array<Any>
        }catch
        {
            return nil

        }

    }


    class func deleteObject(user:CountryInfo) ->Bool{
        let context = getContext()
        context.delete(user)
        do
        {
            try context.save()
            return true
        }catch{
            return false
        }
    }

    //Clean delete

    class func cleanDelete () ->Bool
    {
        let context = getContext()
        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: CountryInfo.fetchRequest())

        do{
            try context.execute(delete)
            return true
        }catch
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe this answer was accidentally placed on the wrong question?