# Core data error: 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Tags: core-data, swift

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

The code simply adds `username` and `password` to the entity "Users" and then retrieves it.

The code was working fine till I added a for loop in it. I even tried casting `AnyObject` to `NSManagedObject` (which is not required as far as I know)

**Code :**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

newUser.setValue("Rob", forKey: "username")

newUser.setValue("pass", forKey: "password")


context.save(nil)

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

println(results)

if results?.count > 0 {

for result: AnyObject in results!{


println(result)

}

} else {

println("No results")

}

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }
```

The error is shown in the line of the for loop: `for results`

Comment: I have copied your code verbatim into a typical Core Data application and it compiles without errors. But this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458209/how-to-print-out-value-from-coredata-dictionary-in-swift-anyobject-does-not-ha.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks.. works perfect.. i wld have voted Up.. bt unfortunately i dont have 15 reputations..neways.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this

```
for result: AnyObject in results! {

            if let user: AnyObject = result.valueForKey("username") {

                println(user)

            }

        }
```

Using valueForKey is the important part

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like below.

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
 let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


 //Adding part...
 var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
 var user= NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
 user.setValue("Rob", forKey: "username")
 user.setValue("Pass", forKey: "password")
 var error : NSError?
 if !managedContext.save(&error) {
     println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
 }

//Fetching part...
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
 let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?
 if let results = fetchedResults {
     for result in results {
            //Consider that the results are array of NSManagedObject, 
            //so the value have to be unwrapped by the key. ie., result.valueForKey("username") as String
            println("\(result)")

 }
```

Hope this helps.